# I trained Python RandomForest and predicts well against test set. But how to predict against a new data set?

Tags: python, random-forest

I have taken some online Python and ML courses but I haven't
been able to find an answer to this question I have.

Now the  RandomForest model is trained and it predicts well against the the data it was trained with. But I want to now use the trained model against some NEW data that wasn't part of the original training/test data set. The has the same columns but only two or $3$ rows (observations).  How do I input that new data into the "predict" function so that I can predict it.

It appears that the predict function requires the same number of rows as the original set. But I only have a couple of new rows to predict. Can some one give me an example of predicting new data
against a trained model?

Answer (score 1):

Use a package that allow training data and test data of different size. For example, from sklearn.ensemble, we can import RandomForestClassifer.

From the code below, we can see that the training size and the test size are different, the test size is $0.3$ of the total data.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X=data[['sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width']]  # Features
y=data['species']  # Labels
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)

clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
```

Credit: The code comes from [Datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/random-forests-classifier-python).